# Coldfusion Webservice Receiving Object

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, bluedragon

I feel like a dolt for not figuring this one out.  I have coldfusion webservice (bluedragon7) to accept information from a partner.  They are passing xml in the result field and it only shows the first element of accessionNumber in the argument.  If I change the argument type to anything else (any, string etc), it throws 500 errors.  Am I missing something here?

Here is a snippet of the function:

```
<cffunction access="remote" name="result" output="false" returntype="any" hint="">
<cfargument name="userid" type="string" required="yes" hint="userid">
<cfargument name="password" type="string" required="yes" hint="password">
<cfargument name="result" type="xml" required="Yes" default="result">
</cffunction>
```

Here is a sample of their post:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
    <result xmlns="http://cws.ots.labcorp.com">
        <userId>peter265974</userId>
        <password>pwd265974</password>
        <result>
            <accessionNumber>0572854881</accessionNumber>
            <accountLocationCode>000010</accountLocationCode>
            <accountLocationName>AERO CONTROL</accountLocationName>
            <accountLocationPhone>2537353350</accountLocationPhone>
            <accountName>HEALTHFORCE PARTNERS CORPORATE</accountName>
            <accountNumber>000804</accountNumber>
            <collectorCOCcomments>
                <abbreviation />
                <commentText>100154550. TEST OF VIEWING CO</commentText>
                <commentType>MS</commentType>
            </collectorCOCcomments>
        </result>
    </result>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: I think you need to model your CFC to match the XML structure, instead of just defining result as a XML variable.  Follow the CF guide for consuming complex object, or if you can, switch to a simple JSON webservice instead of SOAP. :)

Comment: Henry, I'm publishing not consuming, and unfortunately couldn't find any information on handling these types......Any references or additional information you could provide?  Thanks!

Comment: I think XML always needs **one** root element. So try passing the result (accessionNumber, accountLocationCode,...) surrounded by `<resultvalue>...</resultvalue>` or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately their side is standard and cannot be changed.  They are using java and passing it as an object.....so, how can I receive this object in coldfusion?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I tried to loop over all elements while checking if the element still had "xmlchild". Maybe my [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533001/get-all-elements-of-xml-body-and-add-to-struct) can help here.

But you have to change the line, where the content of your body will be saved in a var

```
<cfset var body = xmlsearch(cont, "//SOAP-ENV:Body")[1] />
```

just insert "soapenv:Body" instead of "SOAP-ENV:Body"